# et al not working for first citation

Tags: citing

I am using `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` to style my reference. I want one author name and et al at the citation place and full list of authors in the reference.  However it behaves strange, for first citation of any reference it gives full list of author, and if the citation is repeated, et al works there. Here I put the code

```
\documentclass[article]{jss}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% declarations for jss.cls %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% almost as usual
\author{Achim Zeileis\\Universit\"at Innsbruck \And
        Second Author\\Plus Affiliation}
\title{A Capitalized Title: Something about a Package \pkg{foo}}

%% for pretty printing and a nice hypersummary also set:
\Plainauthor{Achim Zeileis, Second Author} %% comma-separated
\Plaintitle{A Capitalized Title: Something about a Package foo} %% without formatting
\Shorttitle{\pkg{foo}: A Capitalized Title} %% a short title (if necessary)

%% an abstract and keywords
\Abstract{
  The abstract of the article.
}
\Keywords{keywords, comma-separated, not capitalized, \proglang{Java}}
\Plainkeywords{keywords, comma-separated, not capitalized, Java} %% without formatting
%% at least one keyword must be supplied

%% publication information
%% NOTE: Typically, this can be left commented and will be filled out by the technical editor
%% \Volume{50}
%% \Issue{9}
%% \Month{June}
%% \Year{2012}
%% \Submitdate{2012-06-04}
%% \Acceptdate{2012-06-04}

%% The address of (at least) one author should be given
%% in the following format:
\Address{
  Achim Zeileis\\
  Department of Statistics and Mathematics\\
  Faculty of Economics and Statistics\\
  Universit\"at Innsbruck\\
  6020 Innsbruck, Austria\\
  E-mail: \email{Achim.Zeileis@uibk.ac.at}\\
  URL: \url{http://eeecon.uibk.ac.at/~zeileis/}
}
%% It is also possible to add a telephone and fax number
%% before the e-mail in the following format:
%% Telephone: +43/512/507-7103
%% Fax: +43/512/507-2851

%% for those who use Sweave please include the following line (with % symbols):
%% need no \usepackage{Sweave.sty}

%% end of declarations %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}
aaaa \cite{barrett2011ncbi}
%% include your article here, just as usual
%% Note that you should use the \pkg{}, \proglang{} and \code{} commands.

%\section[About Java]{About \proglang{Java}}
%% Note: If there is markup in \(sub)section, then it has to be escape as above.
\newpage
bbbbb \cite{parkinson2010arrayexpress}

\newpage
cccccc \cite{acharya2010novel}

\newpage
dddddd \cite{hubbell2002robust}

\newpage
aaaa \cite{barrett2011ncbi}

cccccc \cite{acharya2010novel}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{reference}

\end{document}
```

#############################################
`.Bib file`

```
@article{barrett2011ncbi,
  title={NCBI GEO: archive for functional genomics data sets—10 years on},
  author={Barrett, Tanya and Troup, Dennis B and Wilhite, Stephen E and Ledoux, Pierre and Evangelista, Carlos and Kim, Irene F and Tomashevsky, Maxim and Marshall, Kimberly A and Phillippy, Katherine H and Sherman, Patti M},
  journal={Nucleic acids research},
  volume={39},
  number={suppl 1},
  pages={D1005--D1010},
  year={2011},
  publisher={Oxford Univ Press}
}

@article{parkinson2010arrayexpress,
  title={ArrayExpress update—an archive of microarray and high-throughput sequencing-based functional genomics experiments},
  author={Parkinson, Helen and Sarkans, Ugis and Kolesnikov, Nikolay and Abeygunawardena, Niran and Burdett, Tony and Dylag, Miroslaw and Emam, Ibrahim and Farne, Anna and Hastings, Emma and Holloway, Ele},
  journal={Nucleic acids research},
  pages={gkq1040},
  year={2010},
  publisher={Oxford Univ Press}
}

@article{acharya2010novel,
  title={A novel tissue-specific meta-analysis approach for gene expression predictions, initiated with a mammalian gene expression testis database},
  author={Acharya, Kshitish K and Chandrashekar, Darshan S and Chitturi, Neelima and Shah, Hardik and Malhotra, Varun and Sreelakshmi, KS and Deepti, H and Bajpai, Akhilesh and Davuluri, Sravanthi and Bora, Pranami},
  journal={BMC genomics},
  volume={11},
  number={1},
  pages={467},
  year={2010},
  publisher={BioMed Central Ltd}
}

@article{hubbell2002robust,
  title={Robust estimators for expression analysis},
  author={Hubbell, Earl and Liu, Wei-Min and Mei, Rui},
  journal={Bioinformatics},
  volume={18},
  number={12},
  pages={1585--1592},
  year={2002},
  publisher={Oxford Univ Press}
}

@article{gautier2004affy,
  title={affy—analysis of Affymetrix GeneChip data at the probe level},
  author={Gautier, Laurent and Cope, Leslie and Bolstad, Benjamin M and Irizarry, Rafael A},
  journal={Bioinformatics},
  volume={20},
  number={3},
  pages={307--315},
  year={2004},
  publisher={Oxford Univ Press}
}

@article{diez2007codelink,
  title={Codelink: an R package for analysis of GE healthcare gene expression bioarrays},
  author={Diez, Diego and Alvarez, Rebeca and Dopazo, Ana},
  journal={Bioinformatics},
  volume={23},
  number={9},
  pages={1168--1169},
  year={2007},
  publisher={Oxford Univ Press}
}

@article{du2008lumi,
  title={lumi: a pipeline for processing Illumina microarray},
  author={Du, Pan and Kibbe, Warren A and Lin, Simon M},
  journal={Bioinformatics},
  volume={24},
  number={13},
  pages={1547--1548},
  year={2008},
  publisher={Oxford Univ Press}
}

@article{ritchie2015limma,
  title={limma powers differential expression analyses for RNA-sequencing and microarray studies},
  author={Ritchie, Matthew E and Phipson, Belinda and Wu, Di and Hu, Yifang and Law, Charity W and Shi, Wei and Smyth, Gordon K},
  journal={Nucleic acids research},
  pages={gkv007},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Oxford Univ Press}
}

@article{ritchie2015limma,
  title={limma powers differential expression analyses for RNA-sequencing and microarray studies},
  author={Ritchie, Matthew E and Phipson, Belinda and Wu, Di and Hu, Yifang and Law, Charity W and Shi, Wei and Smyth, Gordon K},
  journal={Nucleic acids research},
  pages={gkv007},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Oxford Univ Press}
}

@article{benjamini1995controlling,
  title={Controlling the false discovery rate: a practical and powerful approach to multiple testing},
  author={Benjamini, Yoav and Hochberg, Yosef},
  journal={Journal of the Royal Statistical Society. Series B (Methodological)},
  pages={289--300},
  year={1995},
  publisher={JSTOR}
}

@article{miller2007simpleaffy,
  title={simpleaffy: Very simple high level analysis of Affymetrix data},
  author={Miller, CJ},
  journal={R package version 2.28},
  year={2007}
}
```

How to fix this issue.?

Comment: Where might one obtain a copy of the `jss` document class file(s)?

Comment: http://www.jstatsoft.org/about/submissions

Comment: The `unsrt` bibliography style can only generate numeric-style citation call-outs. Yet, as you say, you're getting authoryear-style citation call-outs (in a format that's not to your liking). Does the `jss` document class maybe load a different bibliography style on its own? Does it maybe also load the `natbib` citation management package with the option `longnamesfirst`?

Comment: I tried both, but nothing seem to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from the user guide of the `jss` document class (backticks added):

> The default in `jss.cls` is to use the `natbib` package with options `authoryear`, `round` and
>   `longnamesfirst`. If you cite any article with six or more authors, the citations with all names
>   should be avoided. This can either be done by declaring `\shortcites{...}` for the particular
>   references or by turning the `longnamesfirst` option off completely. The latter can be done
>   by using the option `shortnames` when loading the `jss.cls` class:

```
\documentclass[article,shortnames]{jss}
```

Separately, inspection of the file `jss.cls` reveals that the class loads its own bibliography style, also called `jss[.bst]`.

Two conclusions may be drawn from these pieces of information:

1. If you don't want *all* author names to be mentioned the first time a piece is cited, turn off the `longnamesfirst` option by loading the `jss` class with the option `shortnames`.
2. The instruction `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` in the body of your document has no effect whatsoever, as a different bibliography style (viz., `jss`) has already been loaded. You might as well omit -- or, at least, comment out -- the instruction `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}`.

Comment: Great !! works perfect.